# MAX(COUNT(...)) - ERROR: calls to aggregate functions cannot be nested

Tags: postgresql, function, count, max, aggregate

I have two tables - `ticket(..,event_name,..)` and `event(..,name,..).`

Task:

Write a query that displays the name of the event and the number of tickets for the event for which the largest number of tickets was sold.

The code below get an error: `ERROR: calls to aggregate functions cannot be nested`

```
SELECT name, COUNT(event_name) as ticket_count
FROM event
INNER JOIN ticket
ON event.name = ticket.event_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(event_name) = MAX(COUNT(event_name));
```

I know I can't use `MAX(COUNT())`, but what I should write instead of it for having the similar logic?

I only have the hint from my lecturer :)

```
COUNT(...)= (SELECT MAX(...) FROM (...))
```

Comment: you can't use MAX(COUNT()) in having statement

Comment: BTW in your query the table `event` is needless. `select event_name, count(*) as ticket_count from ticket group by event_name order by ticket_count desc limit 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rank the events based on the count, e.g. using the window function `dense_rank()`.

```
select event_name, ticket_count
from (
  select event_name, 
         count(*) as ticket_count,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from ticket
  group by event_name
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

The window function `dense_rank()` is applied *after* the `group by` and will calculate the rank based on the number of tickets for that event. Because of the `order by ... DESC` the even with the highest number of tickets will get a rank of 1.

If there are two events with the same highest number of tickets, both will be listed. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

Note that I also removed the `event` table from the query as it is not needed for this.

Answer (score 1):

A simplest solution I can think of is making use of ordering and LIMIT 1.

```
SELECT
  name, COUNT(event_name) as ticket_count
FROM event
  LEFT JOIN ticket ON event.name = ticket.event_name
GROUP BY
  name
ORDER BY
  ticket_count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

(using LEFT JOIN as you may have events without tickets I guess)